# Active the node log in azure application insights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights

Have enabled Azure application insights. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs

Want to log the output from my express Node JS application:

```
GET /api/loggedin 304 6.377 ms - -
GET /api/xx 304 31.052 ms - -
hello // a console.log
GET /api/loggedin 304 5.127 ms -
```

Where can I see the console.log data? Can't find it.

Comment: where do you check your message in azure portal? you should click the Search button on the left blade of application insights resource on azure portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**:

As per this [doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#configuration) -> in the note section, it mentions that "**Note that by default setAutoCollectConsole is configured to exclude calls to console.log (and other console methods)**".

So if you want to change this behavior to collect the console log, you should use this line of code: `setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)`

---

If you configure your node project correctly, then in the azure portal -> your application insights -> click the "Search" in the left blade:

[image]

then set the "Local time", and "Event type", at last click the "Refresh" button:

[image]

Or if you know [application insights query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview), you can also click the "Logs(Analytics)" button to write your own log query code:

[image]

Comment: I can only see the http trafic logs. Not my express node js log. I need to have my console.logs as I need to debug internal logic in my node js app.

Comment: @Joe, have you do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#sdk-configuration) in your code?

Comment: @joe, just want to confirm, you have this code setAutoCollectConsole(true,true), right? Check Note section in this [article](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/#configuration).

Comment: Yes I have setAutoCollectConsole(true).

Comment: @Joe, there should be 2 true in the method, like this setAutoCollectConsole(true,true).

Comment: Success! Add in answer and I'll approve.

Comment: Turns our only the first argument provided to console.log/warn/error is being sent to azure application insights for me..